# AMPScript with Marketing Cloud Connector

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, marketing-cloud-connect

We are sending emails to Salesforce Leads from Marketing Cloud.  These emails have AMPScript variables (First Name, Last Name etc.)

Email is going fine but the AMPScript variables are showing as blank. I also mapped the profile attributes with Lead object fields but its still not working.

On further investigation, I found out that syncronized data source is not set up which is preventing the values to flow from Salesforce to SFMC. On checking with Salesforce, I also came to know that sycronized data sources cannot be set up at Business Unit level. It can only be set up for Top Level business unit.

Now, am stuck at this point. How to pass the values of AMPScript variables from Salesforce to SFMC?

Any suggestions would be immense help.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: How are your email definitions configured in SFMC?  Triggers?  Salesforce Sends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access these values directly in Salesforce, by using RetrieveSalesforceObjects function from your email:

```
set @store = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Store__c", "Name,Address__c,Phone__c,StoreId__c", "Id", "=", @Store__c)
set @store_name = field(Row(@store,1), "Name")
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes I tried that and it did the trick for me :)

Answer (score 1):

As an extra point, I've found that using RetrieveSalesforceObjects is great unless you're doing a lot of loops as it can time out from the bulk of processing. If that's the case you could set up synchronised data extensions and query the salesforce data that way as it reduces the processing and limits errors.